# Cannot ping other IP addresses on same subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, ping

I have a Windows 10 laptop that cannot ping any other machines on the same subnet.  It can access internet sites, but the linux server or network printer on the same subnet are unavailable.

I have tried setting the IP address to a static one on the network, disabled the Wired Ethernet port (The laptop is connected via Wireless), turned off a second access point in the house so that it connects to the router the server and printer are hardwired to, nothing helped.  Occasionally the laptop will be able to connect but it's hit or miss.

Any ideas I can try out would be helpful.

Comment: Are all devices on the subnet using the same [subnet mask](https://www.iplocation.net/subnet-mask)? Are the wired devices in the same subnet that the Windows system is using for its wireless connection? Though you are experiencing a problem pinging the Linux server from the Windows system, can you ping the Windows laptop from the Linux server? Can you ping the printer from the Linux server?

Comment: Are all the devices connected via wireless? Some routers by default segregate wired and wireless.

Comment: Does ping work if you use a different wired device? Perhaps the devices you are pinging do not respond to pings.

Comment: You should also check your router, especially its DHCP client list and its log, both after you have made one of the occasional connections and after a failure to connect. I presume you are using IP addresses when you ping.

Comment: Trying to use "pathping" or "tracert" to see where it blocks. Maybe using wireshark or tcpdump to see some traffic. Perhaps it's an issue with ipv6.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the exact same problem. All the Linux computers on the subnet can ping each other, but the Windows 10 computer can only ping the gateway, not any of the hosts on the subnet.

i.e.

I have Windows 10 computer attached by Ethernet to a switch/router. The router is subnet `192.168.123.0/255.255.255.0` and DHCP assigns the address `192.168.123.241` to the Windows 10 computer.

The Windows 10 computer can ping and ARP from `192.168.123.1` (the gateway of the router). But it cannot ping and ARP hosts on `192.168.123.6` and `192.168.123.7`.

Hosts `192.168.123.6` and `192.168.123.7` can see and ping each other, but they cannot ping `192.168.123.241`.

All hosts have the same MAC address for ARP entry `192.168.123.1` (the gateway).

**The Cause**

I'd upgraded my router software, and in doing so the built-in Ethernet switch was no longer forwarding between ports. My other two hosts were on a different switch and could communicate with each other, and they could communicate with the router because the router's switch was delivering packets to the destination but not forwarding between Ethernet ports.

The solution was to reconfigure OpenWRT/LEDE to set all switch ports to the same VLAN so that traffic would be forwarded between ports.